# Creating nested lists and pairing them using for loop inline

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

n is the total number of Input our array needs.
As the goal is to print the pair of numbers which is taken as input.
I wanted to find the output of this 3rd line mention below and as i hit enter in python ide, I got this result.
I am a bit confused that how this 3rd line in the code works. As i am learning new things daily this problem came ahead and i was struck on 3rd line.

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
arr = [arr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, n*2, 2)]
print(arr)
```

1st input -

```
4    
1 3 2 4 6 8 9 10
```

2nd input -

```
4    
6 8 1 9 2 4 4 7
```

1st Output -

```
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [6, 8], [9, 10]]
```

2nd Output -

```
[[6, 8], [1, 9], [2, 4], [4, 7]]
```

Comment: P.s. I am not able to find "arr[i:i+2]" related information anywhere, but thanks for this awesome platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good technique for understanding one-liners like this is to expand the one-liner one step at a time.

Consider consider this input:

```
n = 4
arr = [6, 8, 1, 9, 2, 4, 4, 7]
```

Let's start with the original line 3.

```
arr = [arr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, n*2, 2)]
```

First of all, `range(0, n*2, 2)` is `range(0, 8, 2)` which functions like the list `[0, 2, 4, 6]`. So now we're working with this:

```
arr = [arr[i:i+2] for i in [0, 2, 4, 6]]
```

Note that `arr[i:i+2]` refers to the two-element array `[arr[i], arr[i+1]]`. For example, when `i=0`, `arr[i:i+2]` = `[arr[0], arr[1]]` = `[6, 8]`. So now we have:

```
arr = [[arr[i], arr[i+1]] for i in [0, 2, 4, 6]]
```

Expanding this out for each i gives:

```
arr = [[arr[0], arr[1]], [arr[2], arr[3]], [arr[4], arr[5]], [arr[6], arr[7]]]
```

Substituting in the values for `arr` gives the final result:

```
[[6, 8], [1, 9], [2, 4], [4, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood it now. I am not getting "arr[i:i+2]" part, but you have explained it good. kudos to you.

Comment: @Martin happy to help! Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation help clarify the `arr[i:i+2]` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

`arr = [arr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, n*2, 2)]` is equivalent to:

```
arr2 = []
for i in range(0, n*2, 2):
    arr2.append(arr[i:i+2])
arr = arr2
```

`range(0, n*2, 2)` is an iterator that yields every other number from `0` up to (but not including) `n*2`.

`arr[i:i+2]` slices `arr`, taking elements from the `i`th position up to (but not including) the `i+2`th position.

So, this expression effectively gives you `[arr[0,2], arr[2,4], arr[4,6], ..., arr[n*2-2,n*2]]`.

Comment: I just tried replacing the loop you provided with the one in the question, but it didn't give the same result

Comment: Thanks, Your answer helped me and I have understood the statement now. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes Whoops, forgot `arr = arr2`.  Should match exactly now.